# Fixing font vertical height issue for multiple fonts

Tags: html, css, fonts, sass, themes

I'm creating a css theme engine and one issue I came across was vertical height issue for different fonts. I read many articles online and all addressed solution for a specific font family. But in my theme engine users can use many fonts as a selection. This vertical height issue is really painful when aligning icons and labels. So I want to know whether there is a way to achieve this.

I created a sample code in jsFiddle please check it out using this URL [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/upb7cL5g/)

```
// html
<button id="arial">
 arial
</button>

<button id="tahoma">
 helvetica
</button>

// css
#arial {
  font-family: airal;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

#tahoma {
  font-family: Tahoma;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

[image]

so as you can see I used `arial` and `tahoma` (please don't mind the button text). you can see how text positioning and space from top and bottom has changed. pixel values are not web pixel values I just zoomed image and got the dimension in photoshop just to show the difference.

Comment: will you share some of your , copy in snippet where you are facing problem for better clarification, Also i found this see if it helps you https://iamvdo.me/en/blog/css-font-metrics-line-height-and-vertical-align

Comment: @AdernNerk I updated the answer. Article you shared with me, I referred this sometime back but unfortunately I couldn't understand the CSS solution.

Comment: so what you want is, get every font-family to equal height irrespective of what style you choose ?

Comment: @AdernNerk I want to center align the text vertically. If you refer above image text is not center aligned.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using the `line-height` attribute.

```
button {
  line-height:26px;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

I set the `body` `font-size` to `16px` to make sure both font families have the same size - depending on the browser `1em` might be different - and removed the vertical padding from the buttons and used a line-height of +10px the body font size to get the same result.

Bonus tip (edited): `line-height` <del>cannot</del> **should not** be used with `input` elements, just use height there instead - details after the fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/5j4L2tpj/

The reason is because in some browsers - Safari for iOS for example - the vertical alignment of text is messed up. Simple `height` property works as expected, perfectly aligning the text vertically - vertical `padding` not required in this case. To sum up, just use `height` on inputs, without `line-height` or vertical `padding` and get the job done as expected an all browsers/devices.

PS You had a typo for the `Arial` font family.

Comment: how did you calculated `line-height`?

Comment: @Ryxle Assuming that the default body size is `16px` and the OP had vertical padding of 5px (5+5=10px in total), then I _arbitrarily_ selected 26px as the line height for the buttons. For normal text I would have used the closest to `1.2 x body font-size` which would equal ~ 20px for better readability

Comment: Bonus tip not accurate.

Comment: @JanKyuPeblik you are absolutely right, thanks for  noticing. I rephrased and added explanation on why I said that.

Answer (score 3):

How about using flex?

```
    button {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }
```

Check the cross-browser prefixes for `flex`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution:

[image]

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->
<button id="arial">
    <span>arial</span>
</button>

<button id="tahoma">
    <span>helvetica</span>
</button>




<!-- language: lang-css -->
#arial {
    font-family : airal;
    font-size   : 1em;
}

#tahoma {
    font-family : Tahoma;
    font-size   : 1em;
}

button {
    position : relative;
    width    : 100px;
    height   : 40px;
}

button span {
    position  : absolute;
    width     : 100%;
    left      : 0;
    top       : 50%;
    transform : translateY(-50%);
}
```

Check the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/upb7cL5g/4/

Answer (score 1):

Well if i understand correctly you are currently using padding/margin to align an element(in your case text) vertically, so if height changes the position also changes as you were calculating the distances so you need a solution where it centers automatically itself by calculating the height. That's what i understand. 
Well i guess you need something like `top : calc(50% - 10px);`

Here's a JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/xnjq1t22/

And This link contains more hacks to align items vertically center http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/FAwku/1/

Comment: If i get you wrong or this wasn't what you were looking for let me know but i did as much as digging and what i understand from my senses is that you want to align different font-family to center.

Answer (score 0):

## That is not Arial.

You have (in the fiddle too) indicated a font-family of *airal*, which does not exist, and is replaced by what is probably Times Roman. The default sizes (at least on my Firefox 57) seem different to me. I'd try to reproduce the issue once you're sure of the actual fonts involved.